# Existence of Solution to Integral Equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that the integral equation
\begin{equation*}
x(t) = \ln(1+t) + 1/2\int_0^1e^{-t}\sin^2(ts)x(s)ds
\end{equation*}
has a solution $C[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Banach's fixed point theorem, also known as the contraction principle. Given $x\in C([0,1])$, define
$$
(Tx)(t)=\ln(1+t)+ \frac12\int_0^1e^{-t}\sin^2(t\,s)\,x(s)\,ds.
$$
Then show that $T\colon C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ and $\|Tx-Ty\|_\infty\le c\,\|x-y\|_\infty$ for all $x,y\in C([0,1])$ and some $c<1$.